# DialogFlow V2 user id?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Is there a way to track user Id between conversations without requiring the user to connect their Google account? Like an anon userId. I don't see any id field in the docs: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#request

Answer (score 2):

According to the latest usage, **conv.user.id is *DEPRECATED*: Use conv.user.storage to store data instead**

For more details, have a look at [this answer by Prisoner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642756/1499476).

Answer (score -1):

you can get userId like this:

```
let userId = conv.user.id;
```

Sample intent:

```
app.intent(INTENT_DEFAULT_WELCOME, conv => { 
    let id = conv.user.id;         
    conv.ask(`Welcome ${id}`);
})
```

Comment: This is deprecated per updated documentaiton:

https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info