# DialogFlow conv.user.id Deprecated - any implications?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Similar to [DialogFlow V2 user id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962924/dialogflow-v2-user-id/49964365#49964365) I am using the user ID from conv.user.id (dialogflow v2) to (anonymously) determine the user in my Dialogflow app. However, I get the log message:

```
 conv.user.id is *DEPRECATED*: Use conv.user.storage to store data instead
```

Does this mean I will (soon) no longer have access to the user id? I understand I can store data in conv.user.storage, yet I need the id - not the storage.

Anyone thoughts on how to fail-safe this?

// Code snippet:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  var userID = conv.user.id;
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anonymous user identity [has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) and will be officially removed starting 1 June 2019 (a year from now). So your code snippet will start failing then.

The fix depends on exactly how and why you're using the id, but for the most basic needs, you can do something like this:

1. Check to see if you've stored an id in the userStore. If you have - use this id.
2. If you haven't, generate an id (generating a UUID is a good method to do this), use this as your id, and store it in the userStore for future reference.

Code to do this might look something like this:

```
if ('userId' in conv.user.storage) {
  userId = conv.user.storage.userId;
} else {
  // generateUUID is your function to generate ids.
  userId = generateUUID();
  conv.user.storage.userId = userId
}
```

Alternately, you may wish to just plan to use [Google Sign-In for the Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) which will get you the Google UserID.

**EDIT:**
userId in condition should be quoted.

Comment: Do you know if  the user storage is shared amongst different voices when interacted through the voice-speaker (which I want)? Because the (deprecated) userid was not identical per person using the same device (https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info).
This also applies to (if) using the Google UserID.

Comment: They haven't clarified how the userStorage is handled when it comes to speaker devices that do not have Voice Match setup, but if Voice Match *is* configured, I would venture you will get different userStorage objects.

Comment: Makes sense. Does make it more difficult if the app is used by a group of people (a family/household - which is my intention). Especially with the IoT/Smart Home proposition they make.

Comment: It has tradeoffs. Also means that outsiders can't access household information. And Google has to err on the side of user privacy.

Comment: So I've tested it with a speaker. Google indicates it creates a unique ID if it doesn't recognises the voice (as with Voice Match), so I have implemented as you suggested with the storage. However, It appears that also this user storage is anonymous and temporary when using speaker voice input. I will try to link to the Google Account to use a Google UserID. If that doesn't work, it might get tricky account recognision.

Comment: Ok, just to report back. Some struggeling later, but the 'Google Sign In Only' using the actions-on-google library works pretty well so far. The speaker does not seem to allow signin. However, my current approach is to - upon signing - store a user ID in the user storage. If I find such a ID in the storage (even when invoking on a speaker), I don't ask for a sign in (if the user exists of course). Seems to work so far. Have to stress test yet. Thanks for the nudge @Prisoner

Comment: If this was deprecated then which ID to use for sending push notifications https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications

Comment: The ID used for notifications is sent when the user gives permission to do so and is not the ID that used to be provided for all interactions. See https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#finalize_the_subscription (If you have further questions - go ahead and ask a new question.)

Comment: Yes, but there are a number of caveats depending on the user's desires. I suggest you open a new question, providing as much information, code, and logs as possible.