# conv.user.id is UNDEFINED so it does'nt keep the data inside the conv.user.storage in dialogflow fulfillment actions-on-google. how can i fix it?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I was trying to save data inside the conv.user.storage and it deleted it every time i entered with a request the storage cleared out. now i printed the conv properties and i see that the id is not defined although the userVerificationStatus is 'VERIFIED'

```
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res })
let conv=agent.conv()
console.log(conv.user)
```

the result of console:

```
User {
raw:
 { locale: 'en-US',
   lastSeen: '2019-09-09T07:37:00Z',
   userVerificationStatus: 'VERIFIED' },
storage: {},
_id: undefined,
locale: 'en-US',
verification: 'VERIFIED',
permissions: [],
last: Last { seen: 2019-09-09T07:37:00.000Z },
name:
 Name { display: undefined, family: undefined, given: undefined },
entitlements: [],
access: Access { token: undefined },
profile: Profile { token: undefined } }
```

the conv.user.id gives the following results:

```
conv.user.id is *DEPRECATED*: Use conv.user.storage to store data instead
```

Comment: You need to generate your own ids, the conv.user.id is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Here you can find the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642756/6351280

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DialogFlow conv.user.id Deprecated - any implications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640638/dialogflow-conv-user-id-deprecated-any-implications)

Comment: As noted, the `userId` is deprecated, and is no longer available. However, this is unrelated to issues you may have with using user storage. Since the verification status is "VERIFIED", you should be able to use the user storage object. I would suggest updating your question to illustrate how you are storing information, how you are retrieving it, and the evidence you have that it isn't working. Including the text from the "Request" and "Response" tabs in the simulator will also help.

Comment: User storage is not the same as user id.